# **Unmatched Entries** pam_listfile(proftpd:auth): Couldn't open /etc/ftpusers

Tags: ftp, centos, plesk, dedicated-server

I am receiving in my log watch the following error repeatedly:

```
**Unmatched Entries**
 pam_listfile(proftpd:auth): Couldn't open /etc/ftpusers
 pam_env(proftpd:setcred): Unable to open config file: /etc/security/pam_env.conf: No such file or directory
 pam_listfile(proftpd:auth): Couldn't open /etc/ftpusers
 pam_env(proftpd:setcred): Unable to open config file: /etc/security/pam_env.conf: No such file or directory
```

1) I noticed /etc/ftpusers not exists on the server
2) Here is /var/log/secure contents:

```
Dec  6 10:34:38 ServerName proftpd: pam_listfile(proftpd:auth): Couldn't open /etc/ftpusers
Dec  6 10:34:38 ServerName proftpd[7862]: 159.253.140.155 (94.195.237.136[94.195.237.136]) - USER userName: Login successful.
Dec  6 10:35:39 ServerName proftpd: pam_listfile(proftpd:auth): Couldn't open /etc/ftpusers
Dec  6 10:35:39 ServerName proftpd[7909]: 159.253.140.155 (94.195.237.136[94.195.237.136]) - USER userName: Login successful.
Dec  6 10:45:51 ServerName proftpd: pam_env(proftpd:setcred): Unable to open config file: /etc/security/pam_env.conf: No such file or directory
Dec  6 10:45:51 ServerName proftpd: pam_env(proftpd:setcred): Unable to open config file: /etc/security/pam_env.conf: No such file or directory
Dec  6 12:38:37 ServerName usermng[11045]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for userName
```

3) Here is pam_env.conf that displays `No such file or directory`

```
# ls /etc/security/pam_env.conf -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2980 Aug 18 09:26 /etc/security/pam_env.conf
```

Please advise. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: I strongly recommend to move this question to serverfault help forum

Answer (score 0):

Try to do following:

```
Make a backup of /etc/pam.d/proftpd:

# cp -p /etc/pam.d/proftpd /root/proftpd

Replace content of /etc/pam.d/proftpd with:

#%PAM-1.0M-1.0
auth required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed
auth required pam_shells.so
auth include system-auth
account include system-auth
#session include system-auth
session required pam_loginuid.so

Restart ftp service:

# service xinetd restart
Stopping xinetd:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting xinetd:                                           [  OK  ]
```